# Databinding to Spinner using Static array using mvvm pattern

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I am trying to apply data binding to the spinner by fetching the static array. I am confused on how to get the selected item string through this MVVM approach. Kindly help me . Your help would be much more appreciated

Here is my xml where i have spinner

```
 <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:entries="@array/service_type"
                            android:id="@+id/company_profile_grade_spinner"
                            />
```

I really dont know how to get selected item value in my viewmodel .

Comment: `String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();`
send this text to viewmodel `viewModel.spinnerSelectedText(text)`
and get it via live data `viewModel.getSpinnerSelecetedtext().observe(this, string ->{})`

Comment: but how can i get notified when spinner item is clicked

Comment: viewModel.spinnerSelectedText(text) inside this method in viewmodel update livedata and observer this live data

Comment: can you help me with code .. i tried its updating only of first time . second time click listenr not notified

Comment: use `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener` inside listener `onItemSelected` methode   set set to `viewModel.spinnerSelectedText(text)` again

Answer (score 0):

You can take `MutableLiveData<Int>()` in your `ViewModel` that provides you the selected item position based on spinner selection. Then you can use it to find item from list that is selected based on position. See example below:

```
class SomeViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val spinnerSelectedPosition = MutableLiveData<Int>() // This gets updated once spinner item selection changes

    /** 
     * Created new mediator LiveData that provides changes based on position change from spinnerSelectedPosition
     * Use this live data as selected item which you can find from list provided to spinner with selected position got from spinnerSelectedPosition
     */
    val selectedItemFromSpinner: LiveData<DesiredItemClass> = MediatorLiveData<DesiredItemClass>().apply {
        addSource(spinnerSelectedPosition) { pos: Int? ->
            value = listFromSpinner.get(pos)
        }
    }
}
```

And add this attribute to layout xml for selection configuration:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/service_type"
    android:selectedItemPosition="@={ViewModel.spinnerSelectedPosition}" // Use this attr for spinner selection notification with two way binding
    android:id="@+id/company_profile_grade_spinner" />
```

Comment: thanks .. how can i do databinding for radio group?

Comment: You should ask different question or edit the same, so that I can understand the issue you're facing.

Comment: ok here itself if instead of static list i want to have list fetched from server . how i do ?

Comment: For an instance, if you've got list from server your ViewModel is intermediate that's gonna hold reference to `LiveData` of that list coming from server. In such case you already have access it locally in ViewModel via that `LiveData`.

Comment: can i not append that in the entries of spinner as we are doing now?